# What does this keywords means in c language

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to programming and after I have learned the basics of C I don't understand the following keywords:

1. `(*char)`
2. `a -> b`
3. `char**`

Comment: Have you learned the concept of pointers?

Comment: I strongly recommend to read a book instead of struggling with the bases of the language. Pick one from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a C book!  I'll tell you what it means though:

1. `(char)` is the `char` variable type wrapped in parenthesis.  You do this when you are `typecast`ing.
2. `a -> b` is how you access a structure field if `a` is a pointer to a structure and `b` is the variable name of the field.
3. `char *` is how you declare something to be a pointer to a char, as in `char *c`.

They could have other meanings too.  Depends on the context.

You edited your question!

1. `(*char)` is how you'd dereference a variable named `char` if you could, but you can't because `char` is a keyword.
2. `a -> b` is how you access a structure field if `a` is a pointer to a structure and `b` is the variable name of the field.
3. `char **` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.  You see this when you have an array of strings.

Comment: Note the edit, it restored some characters lost along the way

Comment: Ay yai yai! That's not fair! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In order, they are:

- dereferenced `char` pointer (read "value at")
- `b`, an element of something pointed to by `a`
- A pointer to a `char*`, or a pointer to a pointer to a `char`

Comment: Really? The second one is C++ specific? Then how would you access a member of a `struct` in C, given a pointer to that `struct`?

Comment: `a -> b` can be C too.

Comment: @Praetorian: Your third question does not support your implication that `->` is defined in C. (It is, but the third question does not support it.) That is because, if `->` were not defined in C, you would use `(*a).b`.

Comment: I stand corrected; `a->b` is valid C. I always have seen it as `(*a).b`, so I guess I made an invalid assumption. Fixed now.